# How to rename an iPhone project in Xcode4?

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I am developing an iPhone application using XCode4 editor. I have to rename my project. I can't create a new project with new name because I have proceeded too far with my coding and there are too many files in the project.

How can I rename my project in Xcode4? I have searched on net but cant find such options in xcode4 to rename the project.

Comment: Generally it is better to go for changing app name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can click on project name in xcode and then click again. The field becomes editable. Rename it and it will prompt you to rename the other files and delegate class names.

Its really simple in xcode 4. Renaming files, folders, groups and project names can be done using the above method.

Answer (score 0):

You can set bundle display name in info.plist. it shows your name with icon. and for renaming the folder name simply select the folder and single click on the name then you can change the name.

When you rename your folder name, you can also change your app delegate class name and product name in info where you give provisioning profile for installing on device.